# iPhone app won't run in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've just inherited an Xcode project from another person and for some reason I can't seem to run it in the simulator.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: No Simulator]

Comment: Not enough information. What eorror message are you getting?

Comment: @skippy I never claimed iOS Device was the simulator?! Did you read my question?

Comment: @Jim There was no error. Simulator just wasn't appearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the project has "Deployment target" setting higher than SDK version you have installed - try to change it to the lower version that is supported on your Mac (or upgrade your xcode to newer version)

Comment: You're right! Thanks. It was set to 5.1 and I only have 5 installed. I will upgrade straight away :)

Comment: I applaud you for realizing this!  Very nice :) +1.